# Shift + Ctrl + C (terminal copy) doesn't work since I installed Awesome WM

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

Since I installed Awesome WM I can't use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy text from terminal (although Shift+Ctrl+V still pastes)

Comment: i3 does have the same behavior, pretty strange.

Comment: in linux you can easily copy with mark the text and paste it with the middle mouse button.

Comment: I don't know why that particular shortcut isn't default on Awesome, but just select text to copy and paste with your middle mouse button. That is the standard way.

Answer (score 3):

As i mentioned in the comments normaly you can easily select the text to
copy the text and paste it with the third mouse button.
The third button is the middle button, if you have no middle button use both buttons.

But if you wish to use the shortcuts and you use xterm with awesome, than you 
can adjust your `.Xresource` file in your home directory.

Add this to your `.Xresource` file:

```
XTerm*vt100*translations:   #override                       \n \
    Shift Ctrl <KeyPress>C: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD)       \n \
    Shift Ctrl <KeyPress>V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)     \n \
    Shift Ctrl <Key>N:      spawn-new-terminal()            \n
```

Then reload using `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`, and restart xterm.

For more information of the Xterm configuration see for example:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-User-HOWTO/moreconfig.html

So if you use xterm this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I'm still using `gnome-terminal`, and weirdly, there is a shortcut entry for `Shift+Ctrl+C -> Copy` in my terminal preferences. A bit odd that Awesome WM would prevent that somehow but at least I know I'm not the only one facing the problem!